# A Levy process is a.s. continuous

Tags: pr.probability, levy-processes

I have to proof this:

If [image: formula] is a Levy process then for each [image: formula] the sample path [image: formula] is, with probability 1, continuous as s=t.

This is the proof:
[image]

I don't understand the conclusion. Can someone explain to me how the proof ends?
Is there an alternative way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Comment: Sorry, I had surgery yesterday so I haven't been able to get out to read carefully yet your answer. Today or tomorrow I’ll tell you if it’s ok for me this proof. In the meantime, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Thank you for your response. Be well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb Q}$This proof is insufficient (where did you take it from?).

Indeed, the logic at the end of the proof boils to down to

> **Proposition 1:** Suppose that for some real $t>0$, some function $[0,\infty)\ni u\mapsto x_u\in\R$, and all $q\in\Q$ we have
> \begin{equation*}
>     e^{iqx_s}\to e^{iqx_t} \tag{1}\label{1}
> \end{equation*}
> (as $s\uparrow t$). Then $x_s\to x_t$.

However, this proposition is false in general. E.g., suppose that
\begin{equation*}
    x_s=x_t+2\pi\Big(\Big\lceil\frac1{t-s}\Big\rceil\Big)!
\end{equation*}
for some real $t>0$ and all $s\in[0,t)$. Then \eqref{1} holds for each $q\in\Q$, whereas $x_s\not\to x_t$ (as $s\uparrow t$).

(The rate of growth of $x_s$ to $\infty$ can be made arbitrarily slow by replacing $\frac1{t-s}$ by $g(t-s)$, where $g(u)$ grows to $\infty$ arbitrarily slowly as $u\downarrow0$.)

---

However, with the additional assumption that the function $(x_u)$ be locally bounded, Proposition 1 would be true. (See also the remark at the end of this answer.) Indeed, let
\begin{equation*}
    y_s:=\frac{x_s-x_t}{2\pi}. 
\end{equation*}
Then \eqref{1} can be rewritten as
\begin{equation*}
    qy_s-k_{q,s}\to0 \tag{1a}\label{1a}
\end{equation*}
for each $q\in\Q$ (as $s\uparrow t$), where $k_{q,s}$ is an integer depending only on $q$ and $s$. Since the function $(x_u)$ is locally bounded, \eqref{1a} implies that without loss of generality (wlog) $2|k_{q,s}|<k_q$ for some integer $k_q$ depending only on $q$.

We want to show that $y_s\to0$. To obtain a contradiction, suppose the contrary. Then wlog $y_s\to c$ for some real $c\ne0$ (because the function $(x_u)$ be locally bounded). So, for any nonzero $q\in\Q$ wlog $k_{q,s}\ne0$ and hence
\begin{equation*}
    k_{q,s}\sim qy_s
\end{equation*}
and, similarly and therefore,
\begin{equation*}
    k_{q/k_q,s}\sim (q/k_q)y_s\sim k_{q,s}/k_q\in[-1/2,1/2],
\end{equation*}
which contradicts the condition that $k_{q/k_q,s}$ is a nonzero integer. $\quad\Box$

*Remark:* For $(x_u)$ to be locally bounded, it is enough that $(x_u)$ be right-continuous in $u\ge0$ and have finite left limits in $u>0$. Indeed, then for each real $t\ge0$ there is a neighborhood $U_t$ of $t$ in $[0,\infty)$ such that $(x_u)$ is bounded in $U_t$. Now the local boundedness of $(x_u)$ follows by the Heine--Borel lemma.

Comment: I believe OP took it from https://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/385/LevyProcesses.pdf, but there the author did mention that the process is right continuous as an assumption.

Comment: @ThomasKojar : Thank you for your comment. However, in the counterexample above, $(x_s)$ is right-continuous, I think (or can easily be made right-continuous).

Comment: i mean cadlag (left limits too).

Comment: @ThomasKojar : Then the process is locally bounded and hence the "positive" part of the answer works.

Comment: @losif Pinelis ok I read your proof, but why if the process is locally bounded, can I say that y(s) converges to c? Because the function that is sin(1\x) for x=0 and 0 for x=0 with x in the interval [-1,1] is locally bounded but the limit does not exist in 0. Am I doing something wrong?
Anyway, to say that y(s) converges to c can I exploit that my process is cadlag, right?

Comment: @Ginger17 : I have added a remark about this. As for your example with $\sin(1/x)$, it is irrelevant if we already know that the process is right-continuous and have finite left limits.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your help!